# How to delete only one occurrence of a key?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to write a hangman program where if a word is guessed, and all the letters are in the dictionary, then we update the dictionary by removing all the letters of the word that are in the dictionary. However, if my dictionary has two letters, (like 2 a's) and my word only has one a, then all a's are deleted. But I only want to remove one a from the dictionary.

I've tried using the pop and delete methods so far, but they have not worked, and deleted all instances of the letters.

```
    for i in word:
        if i in self.hand.keys():
            del self.hand[i]
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

For a test case, myHand = Hand(7), creates a hand, which is a dictionary, of length 7. I then update the hand by passing: myHand.update('za'), where the word is 'za'. I created a dummy hand 'aazzmsp'. When I update the hand however, the resulting new hand is msp, instead of azmsp, and this is because the code deleted all instances of a and z, whereas it should of deleted just one a and one z.

Comment: if I get that correctly, you want to remove certain characters from a string? Did you try to use the `count` parameter of the `.replace` method? Setting it to 1 like so: `string.replace(letter, '', 1)` would only remove one occurance of letter.

Comment: you should use `break` instead of `continue` to exit `for` loop after first deletion. Or use `return` instead of `continue` if it is code in function. Frankly, `continue` in current code is useless.